# How to Traversal this?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am working on an application that has a web based backend and a Android app based front end.
The backend is used to input data into MySQl (using PHP) and then generate a JSON which is then supplied to the Android App (front end) and displayed.

So here is what I have:
This is my Database

```sql
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tddept` (
  `deptId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `deptName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `deptIsRoot` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `deptHasChild` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `deptParentId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`deptId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=16 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tddept`
--

INSERT INTO `tddept` (`deptId`, `deptName`, `deptIsRoot`, `deptHasChild`, `deptParentId`) VALUES
(2, 'One', 1, 1, 0),
(3, 'Two', 1, 1, 0),
(4, 'Three', 1, 1, 0),
(5, 'One1', 0, 0, 2),
(6, 'One2', 0, 0, 2),
(7, 'One3', 0, 0, 2),
(12, 'Two1', 0, 0, 3),
(13, 'Three1', 0, 0, 4),
(14, 'Dept1', 1, 1, 0),
(15, 'dept1.1', 0, 0, 14);
```

My intention is simple to create a tree structure. only that there are multiple root nodes. and hence multiple leafs.

If put in simple words, I am trying to create a directory tree structure. I would want to display the data in the above table in to a dropdown menu (i.e. using `<select>` and `<option>`) as:

- One
- - One1
- - One2
- - One3
- Two
- - Two1
- Three
- - Three1
- Dept1
- - dept1.1

Where One, Two, Three, Dept1 are root departments while the rest are sub-departments.
There can definitely be situations in the future where in I might have to have something like:
- One
- - One1
- - - One1a
- - - One1b
so on and so forth.

How can I traversal through them using Core PHP and how can I display them in the very structure as above in to a `<select>`/`<option>` (dropdown) menu.

PS: any heads up on JSON would also be a great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution for [image2](http://genxcoders.in/demo/TDirectory/2.png)

`echo '<select>';`

`structureTree(0,0);`

`echo '</select>';`

`function structureTree($deptParentId, $level){`

```
$result = getDataFromDb($deptParentId); // change this into SQL
foreach($result as $result){
    echo '<option value="'.$deptParentId.'">'.str_repeat('-',$level).$result['deptName'].'</option>';
    structureTree($result['deptId'], $level+2);
}
```

`}`

`// mocking database record
function getDataFromDb($deptParentId)
{`

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'deptId' => 1,
        'deptName' => 'IT',
        'deptParentId' => 0,
    ),
    array(
        'deptId' => 2,
        'deptName' => 'Human Resources',
        'deptParentId' => 1,    
    ),
    array(
        'deptId' => 3,
        'deptName' => 'Opreational',
        'deptParentId' => 1,    
    ),
    array(
        'deptId' => 4,
        'deptName' => 'Networking Department',
        'deptParentId' => 1,
    ),
    array(
        'deptId' => 5,
        'deptName' => 'Software Development',
        'deptParentId' => 1,    
    ),
    array(
        'deptId' => 6,
        'deptName' => 'Mobile Software Development',
        'deptParentId' => 5,    
    ),
    array(
        'deptId' => 7,
        'deptName' => 'ERP',
        'deptParentId' => 5,    
    ),
    array(
        'deptId' => 8,
        'deptName' => 'Product Development',
        'deptParentId' => 5,    
    ),
);
$result = array();
foreach ($data as $record) {
    if ($record['deptParentId'] === $deptParentId) {
        $result[] = $record;
    }
}

return $result;
```

`}`

regarding [1.png](http://genxcoders.in/demo/TDirectory/1.png) Here's the `SQL` based on your sample db table

`SELEC dep.deptId As DepId`

`,dep.deptName As DepartmenName`

`,parent.deptId As ParentId`

`,parent.deptName As ParentDepartmentName`

`FROM tddept As dep`

`JOIN tddept As parent ON parent.deptParentId = dep.deptId;`

Comment: It did work. But i have a concern in this to...
Please view [image](http://www.genxcoders.in/demo/TDirectory/3.png).

Comment: The issue is that the Department 2.2 is indenting to 5th level whereas it is a first level department. how can that be handled?

Also, any luck with the first image link? Coz using the provided code and tweaking it was also not yielding the desired table structure.

Comment: Hi @GenXCoders, I Updated the logic for parent and child indention.

Answer (score 0):

recursion is the solution for this problem. While the parent still has a child then it keeps querying until there's no child left.

e.g

One
 .One1
 .One2
 .One3

Here's the php application

`function structureTree($depParentId = 0){`

```
    $result = queryFunction("SELECT *FROM 
                          tddept WHERE deptParentId = '$depParentId'");
   foreach($results as $result){ 
         echo $result['deptName'].'<br/>';
         structureTree($resultp['deptParentId']);
   }
```

`}`

`structureTree();`

Comment: I am actually aiming to get the stuff working into a dropdown.

But this function is only fetching me the top departments. What i want to acheive is that if the dropdown is clicked, then the parent dept need to be shown and then below them their childs.

even i have a table where i hve coulmns:
--------------------------------------------------------------------
|   Department name   |  Departments' Parent Name  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------

how can i achieve this?

Comment: ------------------------------------------------------------‌​---- 
    | Department name | Departments' Parent Name  |
    ----------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: so based on your example you're aiming for this kind of output in a drop down?

--- One1 | One2 | One3 | One
--- Two1  | Two                                                                                                       

Please give an specific output based on the table above.

Comment: Hi!
I have uploaded two images of what I have to achieve. I will split it into three answers due to lack of space.

Comment: 1. [link](http://genxcoders.in/demo/TDirectory/2.png) : In this image you can see how I would want to get the data into the dropdown. The Parents and Childs need to be indented according to their status. For example,
i. IT is parent for, Human Resources, Operational, Networking Dept., Software Development, IT Consulting, Game Development, etc. So, when IT is listed, the Parent Department name shall remain blank, while for the rest, the Parent Department Name should be displayed as IT.

Comment: ii. Also, if you see, the department Software development has the following child nodes, viz. ERP, Product Development, website Development, Dummy Departments. In this scenario, when any of the departments is listed, the Parent Department Name for them should be Software Development. and so on.

Comment: 2. [link](http://genxcoders.in/demo/TDirectory/1.png) : This is another place where I need to place the data. As you can see the columns Department Name and Parent Department Name, the data needs to be filled in as such that:

Comment: i. If the Department is a root, then the Parent Department Name column will be blank
ii. If the Department is a Child, then only the immediate Parent Department Name needs to be displayed.

One this that i feel i skipped mentioning earlier is that, there can be multiple Root Departments. In the above example i have considered only One (i.e. IT).